# Use NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download only part of a file

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlsession

I am trying to use NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download a large file. However, I only want to download the first 10MB of that file. I know how to cancel the operation once 10MB has been downloaded, but how do I force a call on didFinishDownloadingToURL in order to retrieve the location of the saved file?

```
-(void) downloadFileWithProgress
{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hayageek/downloads/SimpleBackgroundFetch.zip"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask =[ defaultSession downloadTaskWithURL:url];
    [downloadTask resume];

}
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSLog(@"Temporary File :%@\n", location);
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 
    NSURL *docsDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out1.zip"]];
    if ([fileManager moveItemAtURL:location
                             toURL:docsDirURL
                             error: &err])
    {
        NSLog(@"File is saved to =%@",docsDir);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to move: %@",[err userInfo]);
    }
 
}
 
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    //You can get progress here
    NSLog(@"Received: %lld bytes (Downloaded: %lld bytes)  Expected: %lld bytes.\n",
          bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the server supports it the optimal solution would be to use HTTP range requests instead of messing with NSURLSessionDownloadTask.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2

Comment: Actually, I want to download directly to the file system, NOT to RAM - so that's why I'm interested in NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Comment: Have you tried using byte-range requests with a download task?  For example: [myMutableURLRequest setValue: @"bytes=0-10485760" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Range"];

Comment: If that doesn't work, there's probably no way to do what you want other than using a data task and writing it to disk yourself (which, of course, won't work in the background, but then again, your app wouldn't be able to cancel the download task after 10 MB of data has been retrieved if the app isn't running either, which probably makes that distinction a moot point).